# Python simple hit game (Sololearn goblin game)

Tags: python

I'm new to coding, using sololearn and trying to make some changes to the code in a simple python game to do with injuring a goblin. It takes two words, the first is the verb and there are a few options of what you can do. Then there is the noun, and only class of character here is the goblin.

Two things I am stuck on:

1. I am wanting to print out the goblin's health and then the comment
   (e.g. "Tis but a flesh wound") after each time he is hit.
2. I was also wanting to add a generic verb that allows for other types of injury; stroke, stab, and have one class that logs that as
   a hit too.

Appreciate any feedback

```
#simple game

class GameObject:
    class_name = ""
    desc = ""
    objects = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        GameObject.objects[self.class_name] = self

    def get_desc(self):
        return self.class_name + "\n" + self.desc

class Goblin(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.class_name = "goblin"
        self.health = 3
        self._desc = "A foul creature"
        super().__init__(name)

    @property
    def desc(self):
        if self.health >= 3:
            return self._desc
        elif self.health == 2:
            health_line = "Tis but a flesh wound"
        elif self.health == 1:
            health_line = "He's not looking good"
        elif self.health <= 0:
            health_line = "It is dead"
        return self._desc + "\n" + health_line

    @desc.setter
    def desc(self, value):
        self._desc = value

def hit(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        thing = GameObject.objects[noun]
        if type(thing) == Goblin:
            thing.health = thing.health -1
            print(thing.health)
            if thing.health <= 0:
                msg = "You killed the Goblin"
            else:
                msg = "You hit the {}".format(thing.class_name)
    else:
        msg = "There is no {} here".format(noun)
    return msg

goblin = Goblin("Gobbly")

def examine(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        return GameObject.objects[noun].get_desc()
    else:
        return "What do you mean, there is no {} here".format(noun)

def get_input():
    command = input(": ").split()
    verb_word = command[0]
    if verb_word in verb_dict:
        verb = verb_dict[verb_word]
    else:
        print("Unrecognised verb {}, not in our incredibly limited dictionary".format(verb_word))
        return

    if len(command) >= 2:
        noun_word = command[1]
        print(verb(noun_word))
    else:
        print(verb("Nothing. Nada"))

def say(noun):
    return "You said {}".format(noun)

verb_dict = {"say": say,
             "examine": examine,
             "hit": hit,
             # "stab": stab,
             # "stroke": stroke
}

while True:
    get_input()
```

Comment: You want to move the super call to the top of `__init__` for `Goblin`. The `GameObject.__init__` is replacing the `class_name` with the `""` value. Actually since `class_name` is a class property and not an instance property you don't want to set its value in `__init__` but rather set it as a class variable again.

Comment: Also, an object's defined class name, e.g., by `class ClassName` can be accessed by `obj.__class__.__name__`. You don't need to set a variable for it.

Comment: Thanks you. So when I change the line: 
print(thing.health) 
so that it links to the earlier: 
health_line = "Tis but a flesh wound"
what do I need to change it to? I'm pretty amateur on this. I appreciate your input, thanks